# knockout if length issue

Tags: knockout.js

I'm a little bit new with knockout and I can't get the `if` data-bind to work...

html:

```
<div data-bind="if: items.length">
    <h1>List</h1>

    <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
        <li data-bind="text: $data">
            &nbsp;
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
model =
    items: ko.observableArray(["A", "B", "C"])

ko.applyBindings(model)
```

sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/gibatronic/EXwrR/

why the `if: items.length` doesn't work? knockout [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) says that it accepts that kind of test. I saw that length is always zero by changing the data-bind to `if: console.log(items.length)`. will I have to make an observable and manually manage that?

Comment: I would suggest making a new computed observable that evaluates that.  Keeps your view cleaner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just change code to use `items().length` instead of `items.length`

```
<div data-bind="if: items().length">
    <h1>List</h1>
..
```

`length` *is native JavaScript array function that operate on underlying array.*

---

Take a look on [Knockout.js documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html). There you can find a lot of useful information.
*From documentation:*

> You can get the underlying JavaScript array by invoking the
>   *observableArray* as a function with no parameters, just like any other
>   observable.

Comment: You should note the reason that its `items()` is because knockout observables are actually functions. Its not clear in your answer why `items.length` is incorrect.

Comment: @Tyrsius There is a link on official documentation where precisely described what is `observableArray` and how to use it..
I've updated the answer.